# Is there a way to get the Long type as a parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I set the sequence value to Long.I want to set it to "/board/detail?id=[board_num]" in the user URL, is there any way? The following error continues to appear:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required parameter 'sequence' is not present.
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'sequence' for method parameter type Long is not present
```

Controller.java

```java
    @GetMapping("/board/detail")
    public String detail(@RequestParam("sequence") Long sequence, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("detail", boardService.detail(sequence));
        return "detail";
    }
```

service.java

```java
    public Board detail(Long sequence){
        return boardRepository.findById(sequence).get();
    }
```

I heard that you can't get a sequence with the Long type. So even though I set the Long value with RequestParam, the error keeps coming up,

Comment: Either use `@RequestParam("sequence")` and perform a request to `/board/detail?sequence=123`, or use  `@RequestParam("id")` and request `/board/detail?id=123`

Comment: Db has set the auto increment declaration as a sequence. Should I still write with id?

Comment: Which request are you sending to your endpoint?